# Most common name for function F in Finsler geometry

Tags: manifolds, finsler-geometry

In Finsler geometry, a Finsler manifold $M$ is a differentiable manifold, together with a function $F$ defined on the tangent bundle of $M$, that is an asymmetric norm on each tangent space. I have found many different names for this $F$, such as Finsler function, Finsler norm, Finsler metric or Finsler structure. Basically, I would like to know which name I should use. Are there any well-known references that I could follow?

Comment: "Finsler metric" is the most common of these.

Comment: I think it's just a matter of choice and you don't have to worry about it.

In the book

D. Bao, S. -S. Chern, Z.Shen, An introduction to Riemann-Finsler geometry, Grad. Texts in Math. 200, Springer, New York, 2000,

the authors define F as a "Finsler structure of M", that, ultimately, defines a metric on M, a... Finsler metric! Why not?